# how to have different Sessions for each tab on IE8

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, session, session-state, sessionid

I have a intranet application, Users are validated against a ACtive directory.
I m using session to store data. using  InProc Session mode.
when the user open 2 tabs does something onthe tab1 and goes to 2nd tab to do someoperation but im seeing the data in sesssion for teh previous results so this is giving some strange behaviour and the user is not seeing wha ti supposed to seee.
i have around 12 variable in session to keep data but all this messes up when the user opens multiple tabs and confuses the user.
is there a way to do it using c# or javascript to have each tab or window its own session
Help me out with
if possible could you provide me some code samples to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot have different sessions in different tabs, because session is domain specific, but you can either change your logic and store variables in FORMs - preferable way, or you can have multiple domains, as it is intranet - you can configure DNS to point all *.intranet.domain to your site, during first call you can redirect user to RANDOM.intranet.domain and put sessions cookie for this domain only, then next problem will be detecting different tabs - use search, there are several approaches, so in new tab you can redirect user to new RANDOM2.intranet.doamin url